# Rewriting a hashbang in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this

http://www.mysite.com/one/two/nearly_anything#!0lJ_PghzRwHtOyL3BkSouCFVh61mV_I0ZUPSipZDKPFW9xc

from which I need to get the hasbang via .htaccess file in order to rewrite it to

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?dbid=0lJ_PghzRwHtOyL3BkSouCFVh61mV_I0ZUPSipZDKPFW9xc

This is what I have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule one/two/[a-zA-ZÄÜÖäüö\-\+]+#!(.*)$ /index.php?dbid=$1 [QSA]
```

If I call the first URL I get a 404 not found.
When I put the encoded dbid in a direct call of index.php?dbid=0lJ_PghzRwHtOyL3BkSouCFVh61mV_I0ZUPSipZDKPFW9xc the script acts as intended.
Therefore the error must be in my .htaccess rewrite, but I can't see it... :-(

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment is not sent to the server; it must be handled by a client-side language such as JavaScript.